# What "Robustness" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Mashable’s video calls Y2K “arguably the first-ever mass audit of a
>   global computing network that had been running for decades.” In fact,
>   “The **robustness** of New York City’s telecommunications and transit in
>   the aftermath of the Sept. 11 attacks has been attributed to the
>   amount of work put into avoiding the Y2K bug.”

Source : https://thenewstack.io/how-the-y2k-bug-returned-on-jan-1-2020/

Hope someone could explain to me.

Comment: Cambridge Dictionary [defines robustness](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/robustness) as "the quality of being strong, and healthy or **unlikely to break or fail**" (emphasis mine). Does this answer your question? If you already checked a dictionary before posting (which you should have done), please explain what aspect of the definition is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

In engineering, ***robustness*** is the state where the technology, product, or process performance is **minimally sensitive to factors** causing variability (Dr. Genichi Taguchi, expert in *telecommunications*).
https://vardeman.public.iastate.edu/IE361/f01mini/olberding.pdf